# Javascript Array splice removes data but does not reset index

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-splice

I have an array of objects. 
It had 3 objects

[image: Print out in console. Array of three objects starting at index 0]

I then deleted them one by one using
arr.splice(0,1)
which I repeated 3 times.
I then added a new object to the (what is supposed to be an empty array)
and printed out the ENTIRE array in console.
[image: Console output after adding object to emptied array]

As you can see, it IS the only object in the array, but instead of starting with index 0, it starts with index 3.
Also, the indexes for 0,1,2 are not there, they are not "null"  or anything like it. their gone. 
What's going on?

This is the actual code for removal. I invoke it 3 times.

```
this.removeSelected = function () {

        //Remove from array
        //I have verified that selFramePos=0 many times. 
        f.splice(selFramePos, 1);
}
```

This object that I keep in each array slot(Just a bunch of data, nothing special):

```
  Data = {
        normal : normData,
        imageUrl: selfDefaults.viewport.src,
        topLeftX: norm(cf.paper.width, vpo.cx, vpw),
        topLeftY: norm(cf.paper.width, vpo.cy, vpw),
        width: norm(cf.paper.width, vpo.width, vpw),
        height: norm(cf.paper.width, vpo.height, vpw),
        rotation: selfRotator.getRotation().rotation,
        cropping:
        {
            shape: selfSelector.getSelection().shape,
            tlx: mathUtils.normalize(cf.paper.width, selfSelector.getSelection().left, vpw),
            tly: mathUtils.normalize(cf.paper.width, selfSelector.getSelection().top, vpw),
            w: mathUtils.normalize(cf.paper.width, selfSelector.getSelection().width, vpw),
            h: mathUtils.normalize(cf.paper.width, selfSelector.getSelection().height, vpw),
            color: selfSelector.getSelection().color,
            opacity: selfSelector.getSelection().opacity
        },
        filters: null,
        transition:
{
    type: 'dissolve',
    time: 500
},
        requireUserInput: true
    }
```

**My problem was that I kept creating new array slots with an increasing index number like so:**

```
        var i=0
        function add2Array () {
        arr[i]='something'
        i++
        }
```

So every time I called the function, it created a 'unique id' of sort instead of working with indexes and positions.

I fixed it by removing i and just using 'push' instead of arbitrarily increasing indexes.

Comment: Please show your actual code, including the data structure you start with and the code you use that modifies it.  I'm also not sure what is and isn't an array vs. an object which could be part of your problem.  Also not sure if you're using sparse arrays that might be confusing you.

Comment: Can't reproduce: `var arr = [1,2,3]; for(var i=0; i<3; ++i) arr.splice(0,1); arr.push(4); Object.keys(arr);`

Comment: Works fine in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z1e72nd5/). Restarts at 0 when repopulating. And also works fine with the push method [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z1e72nd5/1/)

Comment: Please show us how you "added the new object" to the array.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you!!!!! That was my problem.
(If you want to write an answer about "make sure you insert objects at position 0 or whatever, I'll mark it as the correct answer")

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich: Done. Though I don't feel it's a proper answer :-/

Comment: I know, but you made me look in the right place.. fudge it :)

Comment: Where's the array in your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> then I added a new object to the (what is supposed to be an empty) array

But not incorporating its new length, it seems. Use `push` to add the item and this will be done automatically.

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich - It is not clear to me how this answer provides an answer to your question.  I gather from your comments that it made you look in the right place, but this question and answer doesn't appear to offer any utility to the StackOverflow community because question and answer don't seem to go together.

Comment: You are right. 
I will add an explanation in my question

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not have arrays the way they are implemented in most other languages.

The docs state:

> Arrays are list-like objects whose prototype has methods to perform
>   traversal and mutation operations.

`ar[i]` notation merely refers to property `i` of object `ar` that could be numeric.

The following is perfectly legal in JavaScript:

```
var ar={};
ar[1] = 1;
ar[3] = 2;
```

We still call it an `array`. But it does not have to have contiguous indices. What should be noted, that `length` property of such *array* will be `3` (the largest value of its *index*).

So the most logical way to think about JS arrays as special objects (see the quote from docs above) with numeric properties.

Comment: Is there a simple way to remove gaps? 
A function that will return your array like this:



               ar[0] = 1;
               ar[1] = 2;

Comment: Without a `.length` it's not an array :-) Or at least, no array methods would work with it (they assume length=0).

Comment: "*`length` property of such* array *will be `3`*". Unless you set the `length` property to `ar` or to `Object.prototype`, there won't be any `length` property, so `ar.length` will return `undefined`.

Comment: @Oriol - true. Made a clarification.